# How to pass a tuple3 as an argument to function?

Tags: scala

I'm trying to pass a tuple as an argument to function. Unfortunately i can't do this. Can you give me some tips?

```
val t = Tuple3(3, "abc", 5.5);
def fun(x: (Int, String, Double) = {
  x.productIterator.foreach(i => println("Value: " + i));
}
def(t);
```

Comment: the function name is `fun` - try `fun(t)` instead of `def(t)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a missing closing parenthese and you called `def(t)` instead of `fun(t)`. Note that you don't need to indicate the constructor `Tuple3` :

```
val t = (3, "abc", 5.5);
def fun(x: (Int, String, Double)) = {
  x.productIterator.foreach(i => println("Value: " + i));
}
fun(t);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a bracket after your method declaration. Also you need to run using fun(t).

```
val t = Tuple3(3, "abc", 5.5)
def fun(x: (Int, String, Double)) = {
    x.productIterator.foreach(i => println("Value: " + i))
}
fun(t)
```